# Terraform overwriting state file on remote backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Most probably I am doing something wrong or missing something here.

This is how my terraform template looks like:

```
locals {
      credentials_file_path    = "~/gcp-auth/account.json"
    }

terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "somebucket-tf-state"
    prefix  = "terraform/state/"
    credentials = "~/gcp-auth/account.json"
  }
}

provider "google" {
 region = "${var.region}"
 credentials = "${file(local.credentials_file_path)}"
}

module "project" {
  source = "../modules/gcp-project/"
  project_name      = "${var.project_name}"
  billing_account = "${var.billing_account}"
  org_id          = "${var.org_id}"
}
```

When I run this for multiple times with different parameters, It overwrites the previous state file.

This is what I see in the bucket:

```
Buckets/somebucket-tf-state/terraform/state/default.tfstate
```

Is there a way I can create different state files per project I run the template for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then it sounds like what you need is [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html).

Just do :

```
# Select per-project workspace or create new workspace
terraform workspace select $GCE_PROJECT || terraform workspace new $GCE_PROJECT
$ Plan and apply as usual.
terraform plan -out .terraform/.terraform.plan && terraform apply .terraform/.terraform.plan
# Revert to default workspace
terraform workspace select default
```

Answer (score 1):

The better oprion is to use GitOps.  You should create an environment for each branch and for every environment inject the correct value in the bucket name.